# Base Class Used With Types, Possible to Assign Generically?

Tags: c#

Assuming the following code:

```
 public class Shared
 {
     public string String1 { get; set; }
 }

 public class ImplementedOne : Shared{}

 public class ImplementedTwo : Shared{}

 public T SetBaseProperties<T>(Shared shared)
 {     
    // go through and assign, return type ImplementedOne or ImplementedTwo
 }
```

I have two objects inheriting from Shared, ImplementedOne and ImplementedTwo. Each of these uses the property String1, however it can vary between the object instances. Since both of them inherit the base class, can I have a generic method that assigns these common properties?

Comment: You don't need a generic method if all you want is String1. What should it return?

Comment: They both inherit the `String1` property, so I'm not seeing what the _problem_ is.

Comment: You can just put the logic in the inherited classes constructors or make a base constructor accepting that value and call it. I don't really understand what you're trying to do but it sounds like generics have no place here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a place to initialize the `String1` property it should be in the base class constructor

```
public class Shared
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }

    public Shared(string str)
    {
        String1 = str;
    }
}
```

And than just

```
public class ImplementedOne : Shared
{
    public ImplementedOne() : base("your string")
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest either implementing a method in `Shared` to set its properties:

```
public class Shared
{
    public void SetProperties( Shared shared )
    {
        this.String1 = shared.String1;
    }
}
```

Or creating a copy constructor for `Shared` that is called by derived classes' constructors that accept an instance of `Shared` (this is my preferred method):

```
public class Shared
{
    public Shared( Shared source )
    {
        this.String1 = source.String1;
    }
}

public class ImplementedOne : Shared
{
    public ImplementedOne( Shared source ) : base( source )
    {
    }
}
```

Update:

I may have misunderstood your question - if you're asking how to assign a single property to the same value for each instance of derived type, I would make the property virtual and implement on a per class basis:

```
public class Shared
{
    public virtual string String1 { get { return "Shared's string"; } }
}

public class ImplementedOne : Shared
{
    public override string String1 { get { return "ImplementedOne's string"; } }
}

public class ImplementedTwo : Shared
{
    public override string String1 { get { return "ImplementedTwo's string"; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the point about generics...

In your particular case you just need a method in the `Shared` class that sets the property `String1`, `String2`...

```
 public class Shared
 {
      public string String1 { get; set; }

      public SetBaseProperties()
      {
        // go through and assign, return type ImplementedOne or ImplementedTwo
      }
 }
```

which you can use on either `ImplementationX` class,

```
 var implementation1 = new Implementation1();
 implementation1.SetBaseProperties();
```

Although, of course, this is something you would put in a construtor,

```
 public class Shared
 {
      public Shared()
      {
          this.SetBaseProperties();
      }

      public string String1 { get; set; }

      public SetBaseProperties()
      {
        // go through and assign, return type ImplementedOne or ImplementedTwo
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a generic method to modify the types, you can use a generic constraint.

```
    public T SetBaseProperties<T>(T object) where T : Shared
    {
        object.String1 = "value";

        return object;
    }
```

But it seems overkill for what you want. I would just go with what Tomek suggested.